# How do I ask a question and exclude jQuery answers to strict JavaScript questions

Tags: discussion

How do I describe a problem on Stack Overflow and tell the society that I *don't* want a jQuery answer?

Every time I see a JavaScript query there is always a jQuery answer - even though it wasn't called for.

*[How to insert row in HTML table body in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333427/how-to-insert-row-in-html-table-body-in-javascript)*

See the replies.

Is there a way to simply state that I want the "raw" JavaScript way rather than an addon library?

Comment: Simply do not put the jQuery tag on the question.  Doesn't mean people will answer with only javascript answers, but you can always make comments on the answers that you do not want jQuery, and it's always an option to down vote.

Comment: Also keep in mind that when you ask a question, the answers are not only for you.  They are for all future readers.  And potentially some of those future readers might find seeing javascript solutions next to jQuery solutions useful.

Comment: To provide an example, you linked to a question (from 2013 BTW) with nine answers, of which only two included jQuery. It appears as if you are looking for solution to a marginal-to-nonexistent problem.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335328/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: To OP's defense, answers over there are wildly outdated. Browser consistency is not a valid argument anymore.

Comment: *"Society"*? *"Community"*?

Answer (score -10):

It seems you have to make your question more explicit:

> How do I insert a row in the HTML table body in **PLAIN** JavaScript?

:-) I didn't find any other solution yet.
If a jQuery answer is the valid one I understand the solution and can port it to plan JavaScript mostly. I don't "accept" or "upvote" that question and write the answer myself.

It's difficult to provide jQuery answers because many developers don't know JavaScript (sad but true).

Comment: I would say "How can I ... without the use of any external libraries or frameworks?"

Comment: "If a jQuery answer is the valid one I understand the solution and can port it to plan JavaScript mostly" - that's a valid point actually, Jquery is also Javascript. There is no rule that an answer's code needs to be copy-pastable verbatim. If the answer shows how it can be done but you need to make a translation of code before *you* can do it... well it's an answer. Probably one that deserves a downvote, but it's still a valid answer.